# Error deleting a Discord message with timeout

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Code:

```js
const discord = require('discord.js')

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) =>{
    message.delete()
    if(!message.member.roles.some(r=> ["TESTER"].includes(r.name)) ) {
        return message.reply(`<:prohibited:814861316715839488> você não tem permissão de fazer isso!`)
    }
    let mensagem = args.join(' ')
    if(!args[0]) {
        return message.reply(`<:prohibited:814861316715839488> você não adicionou algo para ser avisado!`)
    }
    var embed = new discord.RichEmbed()
    .setColor("RANDOM")
    .setAuthor('SERVER - AVISO', bot.user.avatarURL)
    .setDescription(mensagem)
    .setFooter(message.author.username, message.author.avatarURL)
    .setTimestamp()
    .setThumbnail(bot.user.avatarURL)

    bot.channels.cache.get(`786364360071053403`).send('@everyone').then(m =>{
        m.delete(100)
    })
    bot.channels.cache.get(`786364360071053403`).send(embed);
}

module.exports.config = {
    name: 'anuncio',
    aliases: ['anunciar', 'sendbell']
}
```

Error:

```
(node:3196) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError [INVALID_TYPE]: Supplied options is not an object.   
    at Message.delete (C:\Users\Pc\Desktop\RemakeTO\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\Message.js:577:60)
    at C:\Users\Pc\Desktop\RemakeTO\comandos\staffbell.js:21:13
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:3196) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:3196) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

What did I do wrong? Can someone help me? This transition to Discord.JS v12 made me confuse myself a lot! The error comes at the time of sending and deleting the "@everyone". I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): _"Write a title that summarizes the specific problem"_

Comment: The error is quite clear: _"Supplied options is not an object"_ at `Message.delete`. There's only one spot where you try to delete a message...

Answer (score 2):

Your current method `m.delete(100)` is deprecated, this method was used in v11. The current stable version, v12, using a timeout option would look like this

```
m.delete({timeout: 100})
```

**HOWEVER**, this method will also be deprecated in the next upcoming DJS version v13. I highly recommend you use the recommended method for v13 and use a `setTimeout()` function

```
setTimeout(() => {
   m.delete();
}, 100);
```

Answer (score 1):

[`message.delete()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=delete) accepts an options object but you only passed a number. If you want to delay the method execution, you can use the `timeout` option like this:

```js
bot.channels.cache.get(`786364360071053403`)
  .send('@everyone')
  .then(m => {
    m.delete({timeout: 100})
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

As of Discord.js v13, [the `timeout` option has been removed](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/pull/4999). The rationale was that the implementation was prone to errors such as not checking if the message was already deleted, and that it was the only method that has a `timeout` option.

You can delete a message with a timeout by using the following:

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  m.delete().catch(error => {
    // If the message is deleted, the Discord API will return an unknown message error
    if (
      error instanceof DiscordAPIError &&
      error.code === Constants.APIErrors.UNKNOWN_MESSAGE
    )
      return
    // handle error
    console.error(error)
  })
}, 100)
```

There is also a [`deleted`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=deleted) property of `Message`, but from my testing it doesn't usually appear to be set to `true` in time if the message is deleted before the timeout handler fires.