# Setting a timeout to delete a message embed on discord.js

Tags: discord.js

I have a basic ticketing system for a suggestions channel.

Ideally, when a user does `.exesuggest <whatever suggestion they want>` (.exe is the bot prefix), I want the bot to reply that the ticket has been sent to staff, i want the bot to delete the user's message, and to delete it's own message after 5 seconds. At the same time, the bot will send a message with the suggestion's author and the suggestion itself into a staff channel.

At the moment everything is working except for the bot deleting it's own message after 5 seconds.

Here is my code:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js")

const channelId = '873769980729106442'
const check = '✅'
let registered = false

const registerEvent = client => {
    if (registered) {
        return
    }

    registered = true

    client.on('messageReactionAdd', (reaction, user) => {
        if (user.bot) {
            return
        }

        const { message } = reaction
        if (message.channel.id === channelId) {
            message.delete()
        }
    })
}

module.exports = {
    commands: ['ticket', 'suggest', 'suggestion'],
    minArgs: 1,
    expectedArgs: '<message>',
    callback: (userMessage, arguments, text, client) => {
        const { guild, member } = userMessage

        registerEvent(client)

        const channel = guild.channels.cache.get(channelId)
        const newTicketEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setAuthor(userMessage.author.username)
        .setTitle('Created a new ticket.')
        .setDescription(`"${text}"`)
        .setFooter(`Click the ${check} icon to delete this message.`)
        channel.send(newTicketEmbed).then(ticketMessage => {
            ticketMessage.react(check)

            const replyEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setDescription(`<@${member.id}> Your ticket has been created! Expect a reply soon!`)
            userMessage.channel.send(replyEmbed)
        })
    }
}
```

I have a working command base handler in another file that makes the command work.

I just need to know exactly how to make that bot's reply in `replyEmbed` to be deleted after 5 seconds.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error deleting a Discord message with timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66421349/error-deleting-a-discord-message-with-timeout)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) function to delay the `<message>.delete()` function from executing.

Example:

```js
setTimeout(function() { // Setup a timer
    userMessage.delete(); // Deletes the users message
    ticketMessage.delete(); // Deletes the ticket message
}, 5000); // 5 seconds in milliseconds
```

Full example:

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js")

const channelId = '873769980729106442'
const check = '✅'
let registered = false

const registerEvent = client => {
    if (registered) return;

    registered = true

    client.on('messageReactionAdd', (reaction, user) => {
        if (user.bot) return;

        const { message } = reaction
        if (message.channel.id === channelId)
            message.delete()
    });
}

module.exports = {
    commands: ['ticket', 'suggest', 'suggestion'],
    minArgs: 1,
    expectedArgs: '<message>',
    callback: (userMessage, arguments, text, client) => {
        const { guild, member } = userMessage

        registerEvent(client)

        const channel = guild.channels.cache.get(channelId)
        const newTicketEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
          .setAuthor(userMessage.author.username)
          .setTitle('Created a new ticket.')
          .setDescription(`"${text}"`)
          .setFooter(`Click the ${check} icon to delete this message.`)
        channel.send(newTicketEmbed).then(ticketMessage => {
            ticketMessage.react(check)

            const replyEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setDescription(`<@${member.id}> Your ticket has been created! Expect a reply soon!`)
            userMessage.channel.send(replyEmbed);

            setTimeout(function() { // Setup a timer
                userMessage.delete(); // Deletes the users message
                ticketMessage.delete(); // Deletes the ticket message
            }, 5000); // 5 seconds in milliseconds
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Discord.js v13 you have to use setTimeout.
You can implement what you want like this:

```
 userMessage.channel.send(replyEmbed).then(msg => {
     setTimeout(() => msg.delete(), 5000);
 });// It will delete after 5 seconds
```

It might work.

Answer (score -1):

[Message.delete](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/Message?scrollTo=delete) has an options argument which is an object, and you can set the timeout there (v13 doesn’t have this!):

```js
userMessage.delete({timeout: 5000}) //deletes after 5000 ms
```

v13 must use `setTimeout` since the feature was removed

```js
setTimeout(() => userMessage.delete(), 5000) //deletes after 5000 ms
```

Comment: I was aware that I should have user `setTimeout`, but when I use `setTimeout` for `userMessage` it applies the function to the users message e.g. `.exeticket <ticketname>` instead of the bot's reply to that which I coded in  ```const replyEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setDescription(`<@${member.id}> Your ticket has been created! Expect a reply soon!`)
            userMessage.channel.send(replyEmbed)
```

How can I use `setTimeout` with that exact message, because using `replyEmbed.delete()` instead of `userMessage` returned an error.